# How to increase speed of google docs apps scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a google apps script which fetches data from spreadsheet. The data is fetched pretty slowly, I think because of amount of data. The first call of this function takes till a second:

```
sheet.getRange(row, coll).getValue()
```

I think there must be away to create global variables which will be available all the time the spreadsheet is opened. I would store the whole spreadsheet on open and access it, which should be much faster. But I could not find this option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use: `sheet.getDataRange().getValues();` it will result in a 2D array containing all values in the sheet up to the last row and column containing data.

For example, if you have a sheet with data in cells A1:B10 and then data in cell E20 the `.getDataRange()` method will get the range A1:E20 including empty cells.

You can then use loops or filters to access or modify the arrays.

Without more information or knowing what exactly you are trying to achieve that is the best method I can give you.

NOTE: Storing the whole spreadsheet onOpen() is not a very good idea because any changes to the spreadsheet will not be picked up unless you refresh or reopen the spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how I can call this function once, and then only use data without accessing the API

Comment: Here I have shared a [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PRTXuenj2Qomw9agC2sk8ywhYwrwnZ5KHLBLyTWclEg/edit?usp=sharing). Click "Custom Menu" in menu, then "Show Info"(will ask for authorization) and then click any row. Then, with delay of couple seconds the info in sidebar is updated

Comment: From looking at your code `sheet.getRange(row, coll).getValue()` is not your problem. From what I can see you are actually fetching the data several times and performing several other operations that are not actually doing anything for ex. `Date.now()` is called 24 times in your script but not actually used for anything? Again, can you tell me what you are trying to achieve? Is it as simple as click a column and output a value to the sidebar?

Comment: I have hidden the file but can share it anytime. What I want is to make the delay smaller. Each time you click on a row there is delay for a second. The number of `getRange()` calls does not matter, because only the first one takes most time. I used `Date.now()` to find out which function takes most time, because `console.time()` did not work for me

Comment: Regardless of what you do there is always going to be a delay of a second or so by the time the command is sent to Google, processed server side and sent back to the sidebar, but I think your code can be drastically reduced. You use `function sheetData()` to get all the data on the sheet (which is taking the most time) but in `function getMediaDataForRow(sheet, row)` you are getting the values again that you want to display in the sidebar?

Comment: There are may be many questions about the code, but the most time takes the API call. So my idea is to fetch all the data and manipulate it within the application. But I can't create a persistent variable which would not be reinitialized each time some function is triggered. The synchronization issue is not critical

Comment: Then you can use `sheet.getDataRange().getValues();` with the `CacheService` to store the values `onOpen()`.However, your current code is fetching the data several times example in `function getMediaDataForRow(sheet, row) {`
 comment out the line `var data = sheetData();` and it will reduce the run time because it is not needed as you fetch the data with `var phrase = sheet.getRange(row, phrase_column).getValue(); `. If you can answer my question; what you are trying to achieve? Is it as simple as click a column and output a value to the sidebar? then I will be able to help you more.

Comment: It's supposed to output few fields from the row into sidebar. Actually i's not my code, I'm just trying to make it faster, and I don't have experience with google apps script. Thanks, `CacheService` must be it, probably you could add it to answer so I can choose it

Comment: Worked pretty well, I decided to cache rows

Comment: Good. If you just want to display a few values in the sidebar, you may not even have to use the CacheService.. If you need some help with refining the code more, tell me which columns you want to display and I will have a look at the code (I already have a copy of your sheet) to see if minimise the the delay.

Comment: Thanks, that would be interesting to see whether there is a better solution. To fetch one single column without 1 second delay would be already great, because it kinda does not depend on number of columns.

Comment: The number of columns will have an impact depending on how you retrieve the information. You said in a previous comment that 'The number of `.getRange()` calls does not matter because only the first one takes most time' I think you should have a read of the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices). So going by your code the number of columns kinda does matter.

Comment: If you want to find out what is the reason why data is fetched slowly I can send you invitation per email to the original spreadsheet